# SQL Join to put rows into columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have two Tables

#### TABLE 1

```
ID       Name
1001     XYZ
1002     ABC
```

#### TABLE 2

```
ID    GAME  
1001   A     
1001   B       
1002   A
```

I want the outcome of two tables join as

```
ID   NAME   GAME1    GAME2   
1001 XYZ     A        B       
1002 ABC     A
```

I tried with a simple join and it gives me multiple rows for 1001 and 1002

#### Query

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.Game
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
```

```
1001  A
1001  B
1002  A

NA
```

#### Actual O/P

```
1001  A
1001  B
1002  A
```

#### Expected O/P

```
ID   NAME   GAME1    GAME2   
1001 XYZ     A        B       
1002 ABC     A
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the ways to do it!

First you need to convert the t2 table as columns provided you are certain about the values of the game.

```
SELECT
    max(CASE WHEN game = 'A' THEN game END) GAME1,
    max(CASE WHEN game = 'B' THEN game END) GAME2,
    ID 
FROM T2 GROUP BY ID
```

This will give you something like

```
 game1 game2   ID
  A      B    1001
  A     NULL  1002
```

Now join this with your t1.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, S1.GAME1, COALESCE(S1.GAME2, '') FROM t1
    JOIN (SELECT
                max(CASE WHEN game = 'A' THEN game END) GAME1,
                max(CASE when game= 'B' THEN game END) GAME2,
                ID FROM T2 GROUP BY ID) S1 
        ON t1.id = S1.ID
```

Keep in mind that this will be more lengthy when the game types increase.

Comment: Thank you for your response
the First Query does not work the way you mentioned
It gave me a result like

 `game1 game2   ID
  A        NULL    1001`